# How can I retrieve data from a Hive table from two columns with non null values and top 500 records in one query?

Tags: hive

I have a Hive table (my_table) which is in ORC format and has 30 columns. Two of the columns (col_us, col_ds) store numeric values which can be 0 or null or some integer. The table is partitioned on the bases of day and hourly. 
The table has approx. 8 Million x 96 records in a days partition and I am referring to 15 daily partitions

Currently I am running separate queries to retrieve top 500 records with value greater than 0 using a rank function. One query to retrieve col_us and other for col_ds

It is possible that clo_US may have a numeric value while col_DS is 0 or null

Question: 
I want to retrieve top 500 non null and non 0 records from each of these columns from one query.

My Query:

```
From(
SELECT D.COL_US, D.DATESTAMP,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY D.ID,D.SUB_ID ORDER BY CONCAT (D.DATESTAMP,D.HOURSTAMP,D.TIMESTAMP) DESC) AS RNK
FROM ${wf_table_name} D
WHERE DATESTAMP >= '${datestamp_15}' AND DATESTAMP < '${datestamp}' 
AND COL_US > 0)T
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE ${wf_us_table}
SELECT T.COL_US, T.DATESTAMP, T.RNK WHERE T.RNK < 500;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your query I can guess that you are trying to get top 500 rows from your table based on date/time that means latest 500 rows where col_us, col_ds both have a value which is >0 but not top 500 from each of these columns. 
As per your question your table may have 2 type of value. for example.

col_us

0
NULL
10
5

col_ds

5

10

0

NULL

or both column may have >0 value.
So instead of 'AND COL_US > 0' under WHERE clause use 'AND (COL_US > 0 and col_ds > 0)' 
But with this condition you will not get any value from above stated 4 rows.
So if you want to get 10,5 from col_us along with 5,10 col_ds then I should say it's not possible using a single query.

Again, as per your question stated "I want to retrieve top 500 non null and non 0 records from each of these columns from one query." ,
I can guess that you want to get top 500 records from col_us, col_ds depends on the value of col_us/col_ds then you must have to use these columns within rank clause instead of date/time.

What you want to retrieve you may get by UPDATE query depending on other available columns but before that I want to request you to share exactly what you want (top 500 based on col_us/col_ds or latest 500) along with your base and target table structure.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for: "So if you want to get 10,5 from col_us along with 5,10 col_ds then I should say it's not possible using a single query"

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. Because you can fetch data row wise only. You will never get data as below using a single query,
col_us
10
5

col_ds
5
10